# Ruby - How do I sort an array based on the value of nested hash items?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have some rather complex sorting to do.

Given an array of hashes, I need to sort the hashes within the array, based on a value in a key of each hash.

For example (given in JSON format):

```
"instruments":[
{"id":1,"title":"Piano","token":"piano","count":13},
{"id":6,"title":"Bass Guitar","token":"bass","count":12},
{"id":11,"title":"Viola","token":"viola","count":12},
{"id":4,"title":"Synth","token":"synth","count":11},
{"id":3,"title":"Keyboard","token":"keyboard","count":9},
{"id":7,"title":"Saxophone","token":"saxophone","count":8},
{"id":12,"title":"Flute","token":"flute","count":8},
{"id":5,"title":"Drums","token":"drums","count":6},
{"id":2,"title":"Guitar","token":"guitar","count":5},
{"id":8,"title":"Violin","token":"violin","count":5},
{"id":9,"title":"Vocals","token":"vocals","count":4},
{"id":10,"title":"Cello","token":"cello","count":4}
]
```

This JSON is the result of a `responds_with` in Rails. Before it gets to that, I'd like to switch these hashes around in the array, based on the  alphabetical order of the `"title"` key in each hash.

Here's a screenshot of a part of the JSON (in Firebug) to better illustrate what I mean:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by).

```
instruments.sort_by { |x| x["title"] }
```

Comment: Wow, it's that easy! Brilliant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ruby sort_by method (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by)

So in your case where the instruments look like this:

```
instruments=[
{"id"=>1,"title"=>"Piano","token"=>"piano","count"=>13},
{"id"=>6,"title"=>"Bass Guitar","token"=>"bass","count"=>12},
{"id"=>11,"title"=>"Viola","token"=>"viola","count"=>12},
{"id"=>4,"title"=>"Synth","token"=>"synth","count"=>11},
{"id"=>3,"title"=>"Keyboard","token"=>"keyboard","count"=>9},
{"id"=>7,"title"=>"Saxophone","token"=>"saxophone","count"=>8},
{"id"=>12,"title"=>"Flute","token"=>"flute","count"=>8},
{"id"=>5,"title"=>"Drums","token"=>"drums","count"=>6},
{"id"=>2,"title"=>"Guitar","token"=>"guitar","count"=>5},
{"id"=>8,"title"=>"Violin","token"=>"violin","count"=>5},
{"id"=>9,"title"=>"Vocals","token"=>"vocals","count"=>4},
{"id"=>10,"title"=>"Cello","token"=>"cello","count"=>4}
]
```

You can use this to sort by the given column ("title" in your case)

```
 instruments.sort_by{|instrument| instrument["title"]}
```

Hope this Helps.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone following on, my JSON is doubly-nested

```
products = [
{:product=>{:id=>866468155, :code=>"TB2", :name=>"Thunderbird 2"}},
{:product=>{:id=>805953484, :code=>"FAB1", :name=>"Rolls-Royce FAB 1"}},
{:product=>{:id=>715919491, :code=>"TB1", :name=>"Thunderbird 1"}},
{:product=>{:id=>767677594, :code=>"TB5", :name=>"Thunderbird 5"}},
]
```

And I was able to sort by name using,

```
table.sort_by! { |x| x[:product][:name]}
```

...note this also uses ! to sort in place, rather than creating a new Array.